# Is it possible to save/restore the call stack in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callstack

Is it possible to save/restore the call stack in javascript?
I'm trying to find a way to implement multithreading in javascript, so in this regard I'm interesting if it is possible to restore the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to save/restore the call stack in javascript?

No.

> I'm trying to find a way to implement multithreading in javascript

***JavaScript***, the language, is almost entirely silent on the subject of threading. *Implementations* have traditionally used just a single thread with it (in browsers, in NodeJS, etc.).

Implementing multithreading wouldn't be possible at a JavaScript level; you'd have to do it *inside* the JavaScript implementation (V8, SpiderMonkey, JScript, etc.).

For instance, both of Java's main JavaScript implementations (Rhino and Nashorn) are fully multi-threaded.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers , In the past I've also sent work to iframes, but hack cough hack.

Comment: @Radio: Ah, good to flag them up for the browser scenario, yeah. Here's the definitive link: http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

Comment: Yeah I am almost exclusively in the browser myself. Thanks for the W3c link. it's an interesting topic for JS for sure. Cheers!